# Crashlytics custom key undefined

Tags: swift, crashlytics

I am getting an error: "...setValue for undefined key]. this class in not key value coding-compliant for the key ENABLE LOGGING"

For the swift code:

```
Crashlytics.crashlytics().setValue(value, forKey: "ENABLE LOGGING")
```

Where value is a boolean that has been set.

what is wrong with this?

Comment: Did you mean `setCustomValue(…)`?

Answer (score 3):

My error: It's **setCustomValue** not **setValue**